# I want to show timepicker.js

Tags: javascript

I want to use timepicker.js from append form javascript.
This is my javascript:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    minuteStep: 1,
    showSeconds: false,
    showMeridian: false
});
var stre="<div class='input-group col-md-6'>"+
            "<div class='input-group bootstrap-timepicker'>"+
                "<input class='form-control timepicker'>"+
                "<span class='input-group-addon add-on'><i class='icon-time'></i></span>"+
            "</div>"+
        "</div>";
$("#divHobi").append(stre);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call timepicker function on .timepicker it search for that element in Dom which is not present at first. what you need todo is

First append element to DOM then call for timepicker. 
Please use below code.

```
var stre="<div class='input-group col-md-6'>"+
            "<div class='input-group bootstrap-timepicker'>"+
                "<input class='form-control timepicker'>"+
                "<span class='input-group-addon add-on'><i class='icon-time'></i></span>"+
            "</div>"+
        "</div>";
$("#divHobi").append(stre);

$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    minuteStep: 1,
    showSeconds: false,
    showMeridian: false
});
```